# Node js and system cron jobs

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I am using [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) to schedule some tasks inside my node app. This package has some API to create, start and stop cron jobs. However, I can't seem to find these cron jobs when I run `crontab -l` command in my OS terminal. I tried both on my mac os as well as on centos.

Specific question:

1. Does such node packages create cron jobs at the OS level?
2. If answer to 1 is yes, then will these cron jobs execute irregardless my node app is running or not?
3. If answer to 2 is yes, then how do I stop and clear out all such schedules cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Giving a fast look at the node-cron source code, you can check that,
node-cron does not create any cron at the OS Level. 
It looks like just a long time out functionality.. 
I suppose that if the node process will be restarted you lost the launched cronjobs.